Powershell copy-items not working when run from c# service
I have a service that reads from a database a string that is a powershell script. The code snippet from the c# service is:
   psi = new ProcessStartInfo(psPath, "-executionpolicy bypass -file c:\\temp\\HeartBeatScript.ps1  -verbose");
   psi.CreateNoWindow = false;
   psi.UseShellExecute = true;
   psi.Verb = "runas";
   psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
   Process.Start(psi);

The script that is being run is as follows:
&{
Start-Transcript c:\temp\PSTranscript.txt
Set-PSDebug -Trace 2
$time = Get-Date
write-host "Starting" $time
$ServiceName = 'UsageMonitor'
$UpdateFromPath = '\\FileShare\Test Software\User\Share\*'
$CopyTo = 'C:\temp\'
$arrService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName

Start-Sleep -seconds 60
$time = Get-Date
write-host "Stopping service" $time
while ($arrService.Status -eq ''Running'')
{
    Stop-Service $ServiceName
    Start-Sleep -seconds 35
    $arrService.Refresh()
}
Start-Sleep -seconds 10

$time = Get-Date
write-host "Copying Files" $time
Copy-Item -force -path $UpdateFromPath -destination $CopyTo
Start-Sleep -seconds 30

$time = Get-Date
write-host "Starting Service" $time
Start-Service $ServiceName
Start-Sleep -seconds 35
$arrService.Refresh()
while ($arrService.Status -ne 'Running')
{
    Start-Service $ServiceName
    Start-Sleep -seconds 35
    $arrService.Refresh()
}
$time = Get-Date
write-host "complete" $time
} *>c:\temp\PSScriptOut.txt

The redirected output of the script (PSScriptOut.txt) is
Transcript started, output file is c:\temp\PSTranscript.txt
Starting 7/1/2024 12:24:00 PM
Stopping service 7/1/2024 12:25:01 PM
Copying Files 7/1/2024 12:25:46 PM
Starting Service 7/1/2024 12:26:16 PM
complete 7/1/2024 12:26:51 PM

The output generated to the transcript (PSTransscript.txt) is:
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20240701122400
Username: domain\SYSTEM
RunAs User: domain\SYSTEM
Configuration Name: 
Machine: LD318077 (Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.22631.0)
Host Application: C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file c:\temp\HeartBeatScript.ps1
Process ID: 60924
PSVersion: 5.1.22621.3672
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.22621.3672
BuildVersion: 10.0.22621.3672
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
Starting 7/1/2024 12:24:00 PM
Stopping service 7/1/2024 12:25:01 PM
Copying Files 7/1/2024 12:25:46 PM
Starting Service 7/1/2024 12:26:16 PM
complete 7/1/2024 12:26:51 PM
PS>$global:?
True
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20240701122651
**********************

I've left the debugging attempts in the code/scripts.
I see the service stopping. I see the service start.
What I don't see are the files copied in the middle.
If I run the same script in the PSE environment, everything works. Service stops. Files are copied. Service starts.
I have a mechanism where I could supply alternate credentials for the PS script to run under. But, that would be inconvenient since that would involve another department.
Ideas on how I might get this to work?

What are you using as the logon account for the C# service?

The System account

That System account (NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM) accesses network resources by using the credentials of the computer account, which may not work in your case.

Kinda suspected that, I was hoping there might be a work around. The location of the files being copied from is a controlled network share. So, it makes sense that a service account wouldn't have rights to that location.
Rant: It would have been nice if copy-items would support a verbose flag.

Understood. Copy-Item does support -Verbose, but that only tells you the intent of the operation. However, not being able to copy due lack of permissions should produce error output, which should show in a transcript. Have you tried omitting the *>c:\temp\PSScriptOut.txt redirection to see if the errors then show up in c:\temp\PSTranscript.txt?

Ensure either domain computers or authenticated users has access to the share and NTFS of the UNC path you are interfacing with if the security context is truly SYSTEM and it's a domain joined machine you are running it from. Otherwise try having just the domain computer object account added to the share and NTFS ACLs: ComputerName$.

@mklement0 This was the documentation I was looking at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.4
You can see why I didn't think it supported verbose.

@Nottoc, it is the <CommonParameters> placeholder in cmdlet help topics that tells you that common parameters, one of which is -Verbose, are supported. In fact, all cmdlets (and advanced functions/scripts) support most common parameters (though not necessarily meaningfully), -Verbose among them; only -WhatIf and -Confirm are only selectively available.

P.S.: To quickly test whether a given command supports a parameter of interest, type the command on the command line, followed by a prefix of the parameter name (e.g., Copy-Item -Ver) and use tab-completion to see if the full name appears.
